# When I pass a value from main report to subreport it is showing as 0 crystal reports. What can be the reason?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

When I pass a value from main report to subreport it is showing as 0 crystal reports. What can be the reason?

On the main report I created a variable

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared Numbervar x;
x := SUM(tble.value);
```

On the subreport

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared numbervar x;
x;
```

x shows 0 no matter what I do :( Help please.

The main report is linked to subreport by an ID .

Answer (score 0):

Where is the formula positioned in the Main Report (Which section? Header/Group/Detail)?

You could use evaluateAfter({@formula_name_here}) for the formula in sub-report, this might help solve the problem.